# Keycode for special character

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to watch for a user typing an @. The problem is that it registers two key codes, one for the shift and another for 2. Is there a way to know when the @ symbol is typed specifically? Thank you.

Comment: Does something like this work: `if (keyCodeForShift && keyCodeFor2)`?

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to use ng-keypress instead of ng-keyup.